# Can't access certain sites requests.get in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

```
from requests import get
get('http://www.fb.com')
<Response [200]>
get('http://www.subscene.com')
<Response [403]
```

---

I'm trying to build a web scraper to scrape and download subtitles. But I'm unable to request any subtitle pages as they are returning a response code 403.

Answer (score 7):

HTTP Status Code `403 Forbidden` means:

> the server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. [Source](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

The server identified your script as a non-default browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) and is refusing to "speak" with it. It's very common to see sites doing this to avoid scrapers, exactly what you're trying to do...

A workaround is to set a `user-agent` in your headers, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

url = "http://www.subscene.com"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)  # <Response [200]>
```

But I advise you to look for a site that provides some sort of API, relying on scraping isn't the best approach.

Comment: Then it is something on your end. Can you access the site directly using a web browser?

Comment: This worked for me. I found funny using `agents` in order to fool... code!