# certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to to a very simple python request using `requests.get` but am getting the following error using this code:

```
url = 'https://www.tesco.com/'
status = requests.get(url)
```

The error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.tesco.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Can anyone explain to me how to fix this and more importantly what the error means?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 17):

## Explanation

The errors is caused by an invalid or expired [SSL Certificate](https://www.gogetssl.com/wiki/ssl-basics/what-is-ssl-tls/)

When making a GET request to a server such as `www.tesco.com` you have 2 options, an [http](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and an [https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS), in the case of https the server will provide your requestor (your script) with an SSL certificate which allows you to verify that you are connecting to a legitimate website, also this helps secure and encrypt the data being transfered between your script and the server

## Solution

Just disable the SSL check

```py
url = 'https://www.tesco.com/'
requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

### OR

Use Session and Disable the SSL Cert Check

```py
import requests, os

url = 'https://www.tesco.com/'

# Use Session and Disable the SSL Cert Check
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
session.trust_env = False
session.get(url=url)
```

[Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests)

## Extra Info 1

Ensure the date and time is set correctly, as the request library checks the valid date range that the SSL certificate is valid in compared to your local date and time. as this is sometimes a common issue

## Extra Info 2

You may need to get the latest updated Root CA Certificates installed on your machine [Download Here](https://www.entrust.com/resources/certificate-solutions/tools/root-certificate-downloads)

## Secrity Notice

it is discouraged to use `verify=false` as its a security risk. meaning that you browser or script can not verify that the data received from the website/url is actually from them (the site you are requesting)

Comment: @geds133 if this answer solves your problem, please upvote and mark it as the answer

Comment: Apparently according to the docs, this is strongly discouraged..

Comment: @geds133 it is, but you know what you're connecting to. see my post for an edit.

Comment: Yes but if I connect to another website this may not be the case.

Comment: check your local date and time is correct

Comment: Date and time seem fine. This happens with a few other websites too but not all

Comment: @geds133 please see my edit, I suggest you download and install the new CA root SSL Certicates

Comment: download it from [here](https://www.entrust.com/resources/certificate-solutions/tools/root-certificate-downloads)

Comment: Could this have anything to do with using a VPN?

Comment: perhaps, but i doubt that a VPN would cause this, maybe if you had a proxy on the system

Comment: requests.get(url, verify=False)
this worked for me! many thanks!

Comment: Crystal clear explanation. Solved my issue!

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I have reviewed this. I would be happy to accept this answer if you add a clear cavear to the answer that the documentation strongly discourage `verify=False` on security grounds. I would not want users have secuirity issues without full knowledge.

Answer (score -3):

Paraphrasing [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287979/cant-access-certain-sites-requests-get-in-python-3) to your specific question.

Response 403 means forbidden, in other words, the website understands the request but doesn't allow access. It could be a security measure to prevent scraping.

As a workaround, you can add a header in your request so that the code acts as if you're accessing it using a web browser.

```
url = "https://www.tesco.com"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

You should get response 200.

'user-agent' in the headers makes it seem that you're accessing through a Safari browser.