# Azure ML CLI - (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED])

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk

```
OS: windows 10 

azure-cli                         2.39.0
core                              2.39.0
telemetry                          1.0.6 *

Extensions:

azure-cli-ml                      1.41.0

Dependencies:

msal                            1.18.0b1
azure-mgmt-resource             21.1.0b1
```

I am using [AZ ML datastore upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml(v1)/datastore?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ml(v1)-datastore-upload:%7E:text=Global%20Parameters-,az%20ml%20datastore%20upload,-Upload%20files%20to) to upload data to blob storage, but getting

```
az ml datastore upload -w workspace -n workspaceblobstore  -u datafile -p data
```

Error

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(.... (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I have already explored following , but none of them solve for CLI commands

[certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

[Unable to get local issuer certificate when using requests in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925384/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-using-requests-in-python)

[certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972703/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-python-request)

Comment: The cause of this error could be a proxy issue, refer to similar issues: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9080) and [certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/23282)

Comment: [Azure CLI - Work behind a proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=bash%2Cbash2#work-behind-a-proxy)